# Error handling in a console application

Tags: java, http, error-handling

In the code below, i am taking an IP, and depending on a command, giving a GET request back. Some of the GET requests have modifiers which are numbers that i can get with another GET request to the same URL. What is a good way to make sure these modifiers are valid so the program doesn't hang?

```
public class UrlTanslatorInstance {

public String ip;

public UrlTanslatorInstance(String ip){
    this.ip = ip;
}

public String translate(String command, String modifier) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    String url;

    switch (command.toUpperCase()){

        case "LEFT":
            return "http://" + ip + "keypress/left";
        case "RIGHT":
            return "http://" + ip + "keypress/right";
        case "KEYUP":
            return "http://" + ip + "keyup/" + modifier;
        case "KEYDOWN":
            return "http://" + ip + "keydown/" + modifier;

        case "KEYPRESS":
            return "http://" + ip + "keypress/" + modifier;

        case "APPIDS":
            return "http://" + ip + "query/apps";

        case "LAUNCH":
            return "http://" + ip + "keypress/left";

        case "ACTIVEAPP":
            return "http://" + ip + "query/active-app";

    }
    return "Command Not Valid";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how can you handle for cases in the switch that aren't ones you've defined?

Use the default keyword to handle cases that are undefined.

```
switch (foo){
case a:
    doSomething();
    break;
case b:
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
default:
    handleUndefinedCases();
    break;
}
```

Comment: No, sorry for not being clear. What i meant to say is when a invalid modifier is used, the HTTP request hangs forever, and i wanted to prevent that before that even starts. A modifier being invalid is determined by a set of ids that is retrievable from the server.